# Four balls in a bag

Tags: probability

Four balls are randomly dropped into four boxes, where any ball is equally likely to fall into each box.

For a fixed $=0,1,2,3,$ let $_$ denote the event that exactly $$ boxes are empty. Compute $(_)$ for each $=0,1,2,3$.

I have computed $(_0)$ and $(_3)$ which are $\dfrac{4!}{4^4}=\dfrac{3}{32}$ and $\dfrac{4}{4^4}=\dfrac{1}{64}$ respectively. But I don't know how to find $(_1)$ and $(_2)$. Could anybody help me?

Comment: You seem to be missing some $/$ division signs?

Comment: And exponentiation signs.  See [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to properly format mathematics on this site using MathJax and $\LaTeX$ so you can properly write things like $\dfrac{4!}{4^4}$ and so on.

Comment: As for the content of your question, imagine the balls are uniquely labeled to assist with calculations (*as you already have*).  Use [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) to count the number of ways to split up the balls into the appropriate number of non-empty boxes, and then choose which boxes (*if any*) were empty and the labels for the boxes that are used.

Comment: For A_2, for example,  imagine the boxes are labeled. What is the probability that no ball is put in the first box, nor in the second box (ie, all balls are put in either the third or the fourth)  ?

Comment: @Nephanth be very careful with suggesting that as an approach.  You will need to be sure that not only is no ball put in the first nor the second box, but it must also be the case that at least one ball is in the third and in the fourth... That is a rabbit hole of case-work that you should avoid.

Comment: @JMoravitz Basically, what I was going to suggest, is calculate the probablity that at least two boxes are empty, and then substract A3, but you're right, this is going to be a bit tedious because of the union…

Answer (score 2):

$N$ balls dropped in $M$ boxes, the probability of $k$ boxes being empty (*i.e. $M-k$ boxes having at least one*) will be:

$$\Pr(A_k)=\dfrac{\binom{M}{k}{N\brace M-k}(M-k)!}{M^N}$$

We come to this expression by first picking which $k$ of the boxes will be empty in $\binom{M}{k}$ ways.  Then, choosing how to separate the $N$ balls into $M-k$ non-empty piles using [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), and then choosing which designated non-empty box each pile goes into in $(M-k)!$ ways.  This, all, taken out of the $M^N$ total ways of distributing the $N$ balls into the $M$ boxes.

In the case of $N=M=4$, that would be $\Pr(A_1)=\dfrac{4\cdot 6\cdot 3!}{4^4}=\dfrac{9}{16}$ and $\Pr(A_2)=\dfrac{6\cdot 7\cdot 2!}{4^4}=\dfrac{21}{64}$

As a sanity check, $\frac{3}{32}+\frac{9}{16}+\frac{21}{64}+\frac{1}{64}=1$, as expected.

Comment: Why multiply by (M-k)! if {N,M-k} already partitions the N balls into the M-k non empty boxes?

Comment: @ShishirOneal because the stirling numbers of the second kind counts the number of ways to partition into *unlabelled* boxes.  We still need to choose the labels for the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

As a standard approach, follow Stirling Number of the second kind or Principle of Inclusion Exclusion.

In this case, as there are less number of balls and boxes, we can compute directly too.

- Number of arrangements where exactly one box is empty -

$ = \displaystyle \small 4 \cdot 3 \cdot {4 \choose 2} \cdot 2 = 144$

where there are $4$ ways to choose which box is empty, $3$ ways to choose which box will have two balls, $\displaystyle {4 \choose 2}$ ways to choose two balls and then $2$ ways to place remaining two balls into two boxes.

Or using Stirling Number of Second kind,

$ = \displaystyle \small 4 \cdot 3! \cdot StirlingS2[4,3]$

- Number of arrangements where exactly two boxes are empty -

$ = \displaystyle \small {4 \choose 2} \cdot (2^4 - 2) = 84$

where there are $\displaystyle {4 \choose 2}$ ways to choose empty boxes and $(2^4 - 2)$ ways to distribute $4$ balls in two boxes. Please note we subtract $2$ from $2^4$ as there are two arrangements in $2^4$ where one of the boxes is empty.

Using Stirling Number of Second kind,

$ = \displaystyle \small {4 \choose 2} \cdot 2 \cdot StirlingS2[4,2]$

To find probability in both cases, we divide by total number of arrangements, which is $4^4$.